# Trying to populate DataFrame via a multiindex slice causes NaNs in Python 3.5 (worked in 2.7)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have just installed python 3.5. When I run the below code (which used to work in 2.7), the values in `df.loc[(df2.index,slice(date,date)),0]` are `NaN`. Anyone know why? Is there a better way of me doing the below operation?

```
import pandas
dt = pandas.date_range('2004-01-01','2004-01-10')
ids = pandas.Index(list(range(10)))
df = pandas.DataFrame([0.]*len(dt)*len(ids),index=pandas.MultiIndex.from_product([ids,dt]))
df2 = pandas.DataFrame([1.]*len(ids),index=ids)
date = pandas.Timestamp(dt[0],offset='B')

df.loc[(df2.index,slice(date,date)),0] = df2 # Results in NaN values.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.values` returns a numpy array of the data you are looking for.

```
df.loc[(df2.index,slice(date,date)),0] = df2.values
```

Your code doesn't work in 2.7 for me.  I'd guess it used to work with an older version of Pandas.